# I tried to make alphabetic sorting algorithm work on my mini anti-virus but it's not working as expected

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers, alphabetical

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 500
#define PATH_MAX 4096

void myFgets(char* str, int n);

int binary_strstr(unsigned char* signutare, unsigned char* letters, size_t sign_size, size_t letter_size, int* position);

int normalScanner(char** argv);

int quickScanner(char** argv);

/*
"Quick Scan"
Parameters:
filePaths --> array of char pointers (points to the file paths the user inputs)
return value:
1 --> on fail opening a file
*/
int quickScanner(char** argv)
{
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* sd;
    FILE* fileRead;
    FILE* sign;
    FILE* logFile;
    char* filesChecked[LENGTH];
    char* sortedNames[LENGTH];
    char logFilePath[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char signPath[PATH_MAX + 1];
    int checkInfection[LENGTH];
    int lenFileO, i = 0;

    snprintf(logFilePath, sizeof(logFilePath), "%s/%s", argv[1], "AntiVirusLog.txt");
    logFile = fopen(logFilePath, "w");

    dir = opendir(argv[1]);

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the directory!");
        return 1;
    }

    snprintf(signPath, sizeof(signPath), "%s", argv[2]);

    sign = fopen(signPath, "rb");

    if (sign == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file!");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_END);
    int lenSign = ftell(sign);
    fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* signutare = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (lenSign + 1));
    size_t size = fread(signutare, lenSign, sizeof(char), sign);
    fread(signutare, lenSign, sizeof(char), sign);

    printf("Scanning:\n");

    while ((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        //Making sure we don't try to check . and .. or another folder (type 16384)
        if (strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") && strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") && sd->d_type != 16384)
        {
            char filePath[PATH_MAX + 1], s, x;
            int characterCheck = 0;
            int startPos = 0;
            int* position = &startPos;
            snprintf(filePath, sizeof(filePath), "%s/%s", argv[1], sd->d_name);

            fileRead = fopen(filePath, "rb");

            if (fileRead == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening the file!");
                return 1;
            }

            //Getting the file length using fseek and reading data
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
            int len = ftell(fileRead);
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
            char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

            fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);

            characterCheck = binary_strstr(signutare, letters, lenSign, len, position);

            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
            len = ftell(fileRead);
            lenFileO = len;
            len = (len * 20) / 100;
            fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
            letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

            fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);

            if (characterCheck == 1 && (*position <= len))
            {
                filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                checkInfection[i] = 0;
                i += 1;
            }
            else if (characterCheck == 0 || (*position > len))
            {
                fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
                len = ftell(fileRead);
                lenFileO = len;
                len = (len * 20) / 100;
                fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
                len = lenFileO - len;
                char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

                fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);
                if (characterCheck == 1 && (*position >= len))
                {
                    filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                    strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                    checkInfection[i] = 1;
                    i += 1;
                }
                else if (characterCheck == 0 || (*position < len))
                {
                    fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_END);
                    len = ftell(fileRead);
                    fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
                    char* letters = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));

                    fread(letters, len, sizeof(char), fileRead);
                    if (characterCheck == 1)
                    {
                        filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                        strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                        checkInfection[i] = 2;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filesChecked[i] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                        strcpy(filesChecked[i], filePath);
                        checkInfection[i] = 3;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    fclose(fileRead);
                    free(letters);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(logFile, "Anti-virus began! Welcome!\n\nFolder to scan:\n%s\nVirus signature:\n%s\n\nScanning option:\nQuick Scan\n\nResults:\n", argv[1], argv[2]);

    //Sorting the names alphabiticly
    for (size_t f = 0; f < i; f++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            //filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] this grabs the first letter after the file path (first letter of the file name)
            if (filesChecked[f][strlen(argv[1]) + 1] <= filesChecked[k][strlen(argv[1]) + 1])
            {
                sortedNames[f] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
                strcpy(sortedNames[f], filesChecked[f]);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    0 --> First 20%
    1 --> Last 20%
    2 --> Infected
    3 --> Clean
    */
    for (size_t x = 0; x < i; x++)
    {
        if (checkInfection[x] == 0)
        {
            printf("%s - Infected! (first 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!  (first 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 1)
        {
            
            printf("%s - Infected! (last 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
            fprintf(logFile, "%s Infected!  (last 20%%)\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 2)
        {
            
            printf("%s - Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
            fprintf(logFile, "%s  Infected!\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else if (checkInfection[x] == 3)
        {
            
            printf("%s - Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
            fprintf(logFile, "%s  Clean\n", sortedNames[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(logFile, "(ERROR READING DATA!)\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Scan Completed.\n");
    printf("See log path for results: %s", logFilePath);

    closedir(dir);
    fclose(sign);
    fclose(logFile);
}
```

This is a program that takes input a binary text and checks if a file in that folder contains that text.

if so prints: `infected`; if not prints: `clear`.

The program works perfectly but I have an issue that the sorting algorithim I tried to make isn't working.

The algorithm is in function "quick scanner" line 363-374.

And also I'm trying to free all the used memory but I'm getting some errors when doing so.

Comment: If the only problem is the sorting, could you please remove the unrelated code?

Comment: in the sorting im using stuff from the other code so its better to have all of the code so if u needed to take a look at it u have it

Comment: The only thing that should matter is the loop after the comment `//Sorting the names alphabiticly`

Comment: alright my bad i will put just the function i want to fix thanks!

Comment: This makes no sense to me: `if (filesChecked[f][strlen(argv[1]) + 1] <= filesChecked[k][strlen(argv[1]) + 1])`. Why are you just comparing a single character in each filename? And what does `strlen(argv[1])` have to do with it?

Comment: i want to sort alphabiticly so i need to read only the first letter and compare them first letter of the file name that's why also argv[1] is the file path so im adding 1 to get the name after the file path

Comment: The first letter is `[0]`

Comment: Use `strcmp()` to compare strings lexicographically. It returns a negative number if the first string is lower, a positive number if the first string is higher.

Comment: oh okay i'll try this now and update to you if it worked

Comment: There are only 217 lines in the code shown, so the problem can't be in lines 363-374.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to compare two names alphabetically:

```
if (filesChecked[f][strlen(argv[1]) + 1] <= filesChecked[k][strlen(argv[1]) + 1])
```

This is just comparing one character in each filename. The position of that character is the length of the command-line argument plus 1, which might not even be within the filenames. E.g. if `filesChecked[f] == "abcdef"`, `filesChecked[k] == "blahblah"` and `argv[1] == "dirpathname", it will try to compare character 12 of the two filenames, but they only have 5 and 6 characters, respectively.

Use `strcmp()` to compare filenames:

```
if (strcmp(filesChecked[f], filesChecked[k]) <= 0)
```

But your whole sorting algorithm is wrong. You're copying `filesChecked[f]` to `sortedNames[f]` whenever it's lower than some other filename. So `sortedNames` will simply contain all but the highest name in `filesChecked`, and in the same order.

You don't need the `sortedNames` array, you can simply reorder the elements of `filesChecked`. There are many sorting algorithms that update an array in place. Here's a simple sorting algorithm:

```
for (size_t f = 0; f < i; i++) {
    for (size_t k = f + 1; k < i; k++) {
        if (strcmp(filesChecked[f], filesChecked[k]) > 0) {
            // swap f and k
            char *temp = filesChecked[f];
            filesChecked[f] = filesChecked[k];
            filesChecked[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that I just swapped the pointers, rather than copying the strings.

Comment: ```
for (size_t f = 0; f < i; f++)
 {
  for (size_t k = 0; k < i; k++)
  {
   //filesChecked[f][strlen(filePaths[0]) + 1] this grabs the first letter after the file path (first letter of the file name)
   if (strcmp(filesChecked[f], filesChecked[k]) <= 0)
   {
    printf("%c, %c\n", filesChecked[f][strlen(argv[1]) + 1], filesChecked[k][strlen(argv[1]) + 1]);
    sortedNames[f] = (char*)malloc(LENGTH);
    strcpy(sortedNames[f], filesChecked[f]);
   }
  }
 }
```
i updated the code to this but in the log file/console the ouput is this:
https://pastebin.com/raw/htvkRu1k

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: as u can see in the console it's sorted but in the log file it's not it's not even including AntiVirusLog.txt in the log file this is really weird

Comment: Your sorting algorithm seems totally wrong. You're comparing names in `filesChecked`, but then copying to `sortedFiles`.

Comment: see the code i just edited
yes because im trying to put them in an array that is sorted

Comment: u can see in 382-411 there i print stuff and write them into the log file so i use the sorted array to do so

Comment: You're simply copying every name that's lower than some other name. You're not putting them in order, since you're copying them to the same index `f` in `sortedFiles`.

Comment: You don't need a separate array of sorted names. Just use any common sorting algorithm to reorder `filesChecked`.

Comment: could you please show me how it will be in my code i really tried to do it it didnt work with me

Comment: ...and you allocate more memory every time you do a copy. Your code is a huge memory leak.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to sort.

Comment: the code u gave me giving me an exeption thrown at the strcmp

also look at the code i updated it and there's something weird that before and after look the same

https://pastebin.com/V4yCDfL9

Comment: If it's getting an exception, it means you haven't filled in all the elements of `filesChecked` up to `i-1`. I'm not going to try to debug your whole program for you.

Comment: could u check the edit i made in the code its really weird that before and after are the same like what pastebin.com/V4yCDfL9

Comment: You shouldn't remove the original code. Now my answer makes no sense, since it's the same as the code in your question!

Comment: oh i didnt know about that im new here

Comment: any idea why the before is the same as after

it's like sorted before that's so weird.

Comment: but nothing sorted it and when i submit it in an auto feedback system that checks it it gives me an error cuz its not sorting

Comment: You obviously have other problems in your program, since you're getting segmentation fault when you try to sort.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/